# NuGet Silent Install with PowerShell via RMM Trigger

Tags: powershell, nuget, silent-installer

I work with the Kaseya RMM tool to leverage different tasks, and recently I have been working to implement Windows 10 compliance checks via a PS script that calls for the use of NuGet and a Windows update package. During the process, when PS attempts to query the install of NuGet, the script prompts for permission to install. As this process has to be done silently, when the prompt occurs it hangs the script. I have attempted to bypass this with both `-Force` and `-Confirm:$false` however the prompt still occurs and the PS script hangs waiting for user interaction, that will never come. Is there a way to stop the prompting from occurring? So far I have not seen anything that works. Below is the current PS script as it is written now. Thank you to all who can assist.

```
If ((Get-PackageProvider -Name NuGet).version -lt 2.8.5.201){
     Try {
          Write-Host "Installing NuGet."
          Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Confirm:$false}

     Catch [Exception]{
          $_.message
          Exit}
}
```

Comment: The point of the message is that enabling the feature, the user can download and execute code that was not published by Microsoft. Therefore if the user is relying on Microsoft to provide security checks and updates, this feature eliminates that trust. Therefore, it would be a security risk if a script could bypass user confirmation. The setting is almost certainly saved in the registry, so assuming you're in an enterprise scenario, you could use group policy to set the registry setting. Although you could probably set it via PS script too, but you'll probably need to restart the PS process

Comment: That's definitely an option and I thank you very much for that idea. In your experience, could the PS script be configured to provide the 'Y' response as a part of the script? So it would answer itself when prompted? I did a quick search and found `ECHO 'Y' | <COMMAND>` but I don't know if that applies to this case. If it's possible, this would be a simple solution to the case without compromising any security outside of this controlled script.